# How Many Genius Mixes Are There in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

Every so often I'll add a couple hundred new songs to my iTunes and discover a new mix has been created. It makes me wonder then, exactly how many mixes are there, what genres are they, etc.

Here's a photo, in case you're unsure what I'm talking about.

[image: http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT3843/HT3843--genius_mixes-001-en.png]

Comment: Generated mixes depend of the content of your library so I doubt that someone will come straight with the right answer. Maybe this question could be turned into a community wiki, resulting into a complete list of mixes names ?

Comment: You know what? That's a great idea kraymer and it looks like bmike already got started on it.

Comment: This seems like a great place for a community wiki answer and a normal, well presented question. :-) I love seeing some non-U.S. genres filling up the community answer.

Comment: Are these mixes actually "curated" or is it just a clever algorithm that combines stuff at random/in the best mix for you? If the latter, there's possibly an infinite number of mixes. And I suspect that's likely to be the case, since Genius is all about automagic matching.

Comment: That's what I was trying to find out, so I'm holding off on giving bmike the answer, until enough time has passed. I like the idea of having a list of Mixes, but if anyone has a more detailed answer as to how it works, I'd be down for that too.

Comment: Doesn't seem like anyone is going to come up with an answer soon, so I'll go with the community-driven wiki choice!

Comment: If and when anyone comes up with a better answer, you can always switch your acceptance to the new answer and this list can live on as long as people wish it to be updated.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I like the community answer the best so far, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> We can crowd source this:
>
> 1. Please type very carefully. Don't split combinations that use "&" or
>      "/"- just list them as you see them. Do remove the word "Mix" from the
>      end.
> 2. If you have Brit Pop and Brit Pop 2, add in ( 2 ) or ( 2 3 ) if
>      you have more than one mix with the same name.

These mixes have been observed already "in the wild."

- Acoustic Blues
- Adult Alternative
- Adult Alternative Pop
- Adult Alternative Rock
- Adult Contemporary
- Adult Pop/Rock
- Alt. Folk
- Alt Metal
- Alt Pop
- Alt Singer/Songwriter
- Alternative Country
- Alternative Pop/Rock
- Ambient
- Americana
- Animation
- AOR Classic Rock
- Art & Experimental Rock
- Art & Progressive Rock
- Big Band & Swing
- Black & Death Metal
- Bluegrass
- Blues, Boogie & Southern Rock
- Bossa Nova
- Brazilian Pop
- Brazilian Folk & Traditional
- Breakbeat
- Brit Pop
- Brit Pop & Rock
- British Invasion
- Canto-Pop
- Celtic
- Chamber Pop
- Children's
- Christian Pop/Rock
- Christian Urban
- Classical
- Classical Crossover
- Classical Instrumental
- Classic R&B
- Classic Hard Rock
- Classic Punk (2)
- Classic Rock (2)
- Classic Ska
- Classic Soul
- Comedy
- Conscious Rap (2)
- Contemporary
- Contemporary Country
- Contemporary Folk
- Contemporary R&B
- Cool & West Coast Jazz
- Country
- Christian Rock
- Dance Pop
- Danceclub
- Dancehall & Ragga
- Disco
- Dream Pop
- East Coast Rap
- Electric Blues
- Electro Pop
- Electronica
- Electronica Mainstream
- Emo
- Europop
- Folk (2)
- Folk Rock
- Folk-Pop
- French
- Funk
- Gangsta Rap
- Goth (2)
- Gothic Metal
- Grunge
- Hardcore & Thrash
- Hard Bop & Post-Bop
- Hard Rock & Stoner Rock
- Heavy Metal
- Hip-Hop/Rap
- Honky Tonk & Outlaw
- House
- Indie Pop
- Indie Rock
- Indie Rock & Lo-Fi
- Industrial
- Israeli
- Jam Bands
- Jazz
- Jazz Vocals
- Jungle / Drum n' Bass
- J-Guitar Rock
- J-Pop
- J-Pop Dance
- J-Pop Female
- J-Pop Urban
- J-Rock Female
- Kammerpop
- Korean Pop
- Latin Dance/Pop
- Latin Folk & Traditional
- Latin Rock
- Latin/World Jazz
- Lounge
- Mainstream Rock
- Mandarin Pop
- Meditation
- Metal
- Minimalist
- Musicals (3)
- Neo-Soul
- New Age
- New Age/World Music
- New Wave
- Nü-Metal
- Old-School Rap
- Pop
- Pop Metal
- Pop-Soul
- Post-Modern Rock
- Post Punk
- Power Pop
- Progressive House
- Progressive Metal
- Punk (2)
- Punk Pop
- Punk Rock
- Quiet Storm
- Reggae
- Rock Singer/Songwriter
- Singer/Songwriter
- Ska
- Soft Rock
- Soft Rock Oldies
- Soul
- Soundtracks
- Southern Rap
- Surf/Garage Revival
- Swing Revival
- Synth-Pop
- Techno/House
- Teen Pop
- Traditional Acoustic Blues
- Traditional Folk
- Trance
- Trip-Hop (2)
- Urban Crossover
- Video Games
- Vocal
- West African
- West Coast Rap
- World
- '50s Oldies
- '60s
- 60's Psychedelic Pop/Rock
- '70s Pop

Comment: I wonder if some of the mixes end up being combinations of "compatible" genres, e.g. someone had "Indie Rock" but I had "Indie Rock & Lo-Fi". Let's keep adding them as separate items (just like you see it in your iTunes if it's slightly different from an item already on the list), then we can figure out if iTunes is doing some smart combining of genres if there are a lot of duplicates joined by "&".

Answer (score 4):

Most macs with screens less than 27 inches get a maximum of 12 Genius Mix playlists if you have genius turned on in the view.

There are clearly more than 50 genres on the iTunes store and I've easily seen more than 20 mixes on various people's libraries. I'm not sure if Apple has disclosed how this is curated or how many categories are possible at any point in time.

You can remove a certain list to make room for another Mix by right-clicking on an existing mix icon. As you add more music and the genius updates, you may get a new mix when it can identify enough music in one of the mix categories.

[image]

Comment: Why on earth would you want to remove the best mix in your list? It has **Phish** in it!

Comment: Asked and answered. ;)

Comment: @IanC Clearly a bug - sadly the baby went out with the bath water - I don’t think there’s a way to visually discover these genius mixes visually with Apple Music.