# Which cities have "flyover" in iOS 6 Maps?

Tags: ios, maps

Is there a list of which cities have 3D flyover data that is actually 3D and not an attempt to map a satellite image on false perspective? If not, could we crowd source this in a wiki-type answer?

Comment: Let's put all the answers in the answer section. You can edit Canuck Skier's answer and eventually it will hold everything or start a new answer. See [How Many Genius Mixes Are There in iTunes?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23577/how-many-genius-mixes-are-there-in-itunes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Australia

### Australia

- Sydney

## Europe

### Denmark

- Copenhagen

### France

- Lyon

### Germany

- Berlin
- Munich

### Ireland

- Dublin

### Italy

- Milan
- Rome

### Spain

- Barcelona
- Madrid

### United Kingdom

- London
- Birmingham
- Manchester

## North America

### Canada

- Montreal
- Toronto
- Vancouver

### United States

- Apple HQ in Cupertino
- Arlington, TX
- Atlanta
- Austin
- Boston
- Chicago
- Dallas
- Denver
- Fort Worth
- Houston
- Las Vegas
- Long Beach
- Los Angeles
- Memphis
- Miami
- New Orleans
- New York
- Oakland
- Philadelphia
- Phoenix
- Portland
- Sacramento
- San Francisco
- San Jose
- Seattle
- Bellevue, WA
- Everett, WA
- Kent, WA
- Tacoma, WA

The initial 11 cities at the time of iOS 6 announcement (June, 2012) were identified by
[Cult of Mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/173690/here-all-all-the-cities-you-can-flyover-in-ios-6-maps-gallery/#aXXYs47u1DKHwfVO.99).

Comment: AnandTech posted a pretty good list: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvHwrTl2t92udGtaY0MtOUcwQk80OW5yWER1elJkb0E#gid=0

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more extensive list from [MacRumors](http://att.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1445449)

Australia (2)

- Melbourne (Flyover)
- Sydney (Flyover)

Austria (4)

- Graz (2D)
- Linz (2D)
- Salzburg (2D)
- Vienna (2D)

Belgium (7)

- Antwerp (2D)
- Bruges (2D)
- Brussels (2D)
- Charleroi (2D)
- Ghent (2D)
- Liege (2D)
- Schaerbeek (2D)

Canada (10)

- Calgary (2D, Flyover)
- Edmonton (2D)
- Halifax (2D)
- Montreal (2D, Flyover)
- Ottawa (2D)
- Quebeck (2D)
- Toronto (2D, Flyover)
- Vancouver (2D)
- Windsor (2D)
- Winnipeg (2D)

Denmark (3)

- Aarhus (2D)
- Copenhagen (2D, Flyover)
- Odense (2D)

Finland (1)

- Helsinki (2D)

France (15)

- Bordeaux (2D)
- Dijon (2D)
- Grenoble (2D)
- Le Havre (2D)
- Le Mans (2D)
- Lyon (2D, Flyover)
- Marseille (2D)
- Montpellier (2D)
- Nantes (2D)
- Nice (2D)
- Paris (2D)
- Reims (2D)
- Rennes (2D)
- Strasbourg (2D)
- Toulouse (2D)

Germany (20)

- Berlin (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Bochum (2D)
- Bonn (2D)
- Bremen (2D)
- Cologne (2D)
- Dortmund (2D)
- Dortmund (2D)
- Dresden (2D)
- Dusseldorf (2D)
- Essen (2D)
- Frankfurt am Main (2D)
- Hamburg (2D)
- Hanover (2D)
- Leipzig (2D)
- Ludwigshafen (2D)
- Mannheim (2D)
- Munich (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Nuremberg (2D)
- Potsdam (2D)
- Rostock (2D)
- Stuttgart (2D)

Greece (2)

- Athens (2D)
- Thessaloniki (2D)

Hungary (2)

- Budapest (2D)
- Debrecen (2D)

Ireland (2)

- Cork (2D)
- Dublin (2D, Flyover)

Italy (15)

- Bari (2D)
- Bologna (2D)
- Brescia (2D)
- Catania (2D)
- Florence (2D)
- Genoa (2D)
- Milan (2D, Flyover)
- Naples (2D)
- Palermo (2D)
- Ravenna (2D)
- Rimini (2D)
- Rome (2D, Flyover)
- Turin (2D)
- Venice (2D)
- Verona (2D)

Japan (20 so far)

- Chiba (2D)
- Fukuoka (2D)
- Hamamatsu (2D)
- Hiroshima (2D)
- Kawasaki (2D)
- Kitakyushu (2D)
- Kobe (2D)
- Kumamoto (2D)
- Nagoya (2D)
- Niigata (2D)
- Okayama (2D)
- Osaka (2D)
- Saitama (2D)
- Sakai (2D)
- Sapporo (2D)
- Sendai (2D)
- Shizuoka (2D)
- Tokio (2D)
- Yokohama (2D)

Luxemburg (1)

- Luxemburg (2D)

Netherlands (5)

- Amsterdam (2D)
- Eindhoven (2D)
- Rotterdam (2D)
- The Hague (2D)
- Utrecht (2D)

Poland (2)

- Krakow (2D)
- Warsaw (2D)

Portugal (3)

- Amadora (2D)
- Lisbon (2D)
- Porto (2D)

Romania (1)

- Bucharest (2D)

Spain (14)

- Alicante (2D)
- Barcelona (2D, Flyover)
- Bilbao (2D)
- Cordoba (2D)
- Coruna (2D)
- Gijon (2D)
- Granada (2D)
- Madrid (2D, Flyover)
- Malaga (2D)
- Palma De Mallorca (2D)
- Seville (2D)
- Valencia (2D)
- Valladolid (2D)
- Zaragoza (2D)

Sweden (4)

- Gothenburg (2D)
- Malmo (2D)
- Stockholm (2D, Flyover)
- Uppsala (2D)

Switzerland (4)

- Basel (2D)
- Bern (2D)
- Geneva (2D)
- Zurich (2D)

Turkey (1)

- Istanbul (2D)

Ukraine (1)

- Kiev (2D)

United Kingdom (18)

- Belfast (2D)
- Birmingham (2D, Flyover)
- Bradford (2D)
- Bristol (2D)
- Cardiff (2D)
- Coventry (2D)
- Edinburgh (2D)
- Glasgow (2D)
- Kington (2D)
- Leeds (2D)
- Leicester (2D)
- Liverpool (2D)
- London (2D, Flyover)
- Manchester (2D, Flyover)
- Newcastle (2D)
- Sheffield (2D)
- Southampton (2D)
- York (2D)

USA (65 so far)

- Albuquerque (2D)
- Anaheim (2D)
- Arlington (2D, Flyover)
- Atlanta (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Aurora (2D)
- Austin (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Bakersfield (2D)
- Baltimore (2D)
- Beverly Hills (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Boston (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Century City (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Charlotte (2D)
- Chicago (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Cleveland (2D)
- Colorado Springs (2D)
- Columbus (2D)
- Corpus Christi (2D)
- Cupertino (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Dallas (2D, Flyover)
- Denver (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Detroit (2D)
- El Paso (2D)
- Fort Worth (2D, Flyover)
- Fresno (2D)
- Honululu (2D)
- Houston (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Indianapolis (2D)
- Jacksonville (2D)
- Kansas City (2D)
- Las Vegas (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Long Beach (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Los Angeles (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Louisville (2D)
- Memphis (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Mesa (2D)
- Miami (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Milwaukee (2D)
- Minneapolis (2D)
- Nashville (2D)
- New Orleans (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- New York (2D, Flyover)
- Oakland (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Oklahoma City (2D)
- Omaha (2D)
- Philadelphia (2D, Flyover)
- Phoenix (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Pittsburgh (2D)
- Portland (2D, Flyover)
- Raleigh (2D)
- Redmond (Flyover)
- Sacramento (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Saint Louis (2D)
- San Antonio (2D)
- San Diego (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- San Francisco (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- San Jose (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Santa Ana (2D)
- Santa Monica (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Seattle (2D, 3D, Flyover)
- Tampa (2D)
- Tucson (2D)
- Tulsa (2D)
- Virginia Beach (2D)
- Washington D.C. (2D)
- Wichita (2D)

Comment: Is there a need for the 2D cities? Or is apple maps actually that bad that the cities not list in this answer don't appear at all?

Answer (score 0):

[FlyOverCities.com](http://flyovercities.com) is a website which claims to keep the updated list of cities with flyovers in iOS 6 Maps

Comment: and it's woefully out of date already.