# How many Genius Mixes can one have on a MacBook?

Tags: itunes

I know there are a gazillion mixes possible in iTunes and that the size and genre of such mixes are determined by some top-secret algorithm running behind the scene. However, I am really curious to know how many one can possibly have at a time on a MacBook. I have read some users claiming to have up to 12 mixes on their 27" Macs but I am using a 13" MacBook so guess 12 isn't possible for me. Currently I have 6; is that the limit? Has anyone witnessed more than 6 on this screen size (13")?

P.S. I am NOT referring to genius playlists which anyone can build with a song. I am specifically talking about Genius Mixes that iTunes creates automatically (if Genius is activated on the account).

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23577/how-many-genius-mixes-are-there-in-itunes

Comment: Re-opened. Sorry, you're asking something slightly different.