# iOS Device Serial List

Tags: ios, ipad, ipod, serial-number

Does anyone know of a list of iOS serial numbers that marries the respective device types to the last 3 characters of the device serial? I know there are query sites out there where you can pump in the entire serial number but I'm looking for a comprehensive list that accounts for all models and sub-models.

In example:

- CP7 --> iPod 4th Gen
- FHW --> iPad 2nd Gen
- 196 --> iPad Mini 1st Gen

I'm trying to avoid compiling this for all devices in my environment but I can't seem to find anything that already exists.

Comment: This could be the place where the internet does the work. Why not start a stub of an answer and [we can all chip away](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23577/how-many-genius-mixes-are-there-in-itunes) at it wiki style? If someone swoops in later with a better resource, that's fine too. Also, are the last 3 even good enough to tell all models? I suppose with enough data we can figure that out too.

Comment: @bmike Yes - the last 3 are Apple's secret sauce. Even reaching out to my Enterprise Apple Rep yielded an answer of "that's an interesting question. Regardless I've added a ton to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was obviously nothing out there in the wild I got bored after a couple of beers and pulled this from half of our environment. The list really does clean up a lot better as a CSV separated out by Device Type / Generation / Communication Type.

```
iPod 4th - 96T, CP7, CP9, NQY, T75, T77
iPod 5th - 4K4, FCJ, MJF, 4JR

iPad 1st Wifi - Z38
iPad 1st 3G - A90, ETU
iPad 2nd Wifi - FHW, FHY, KPH
iPad 2nd GSM - FJ1, FJ2
iPad 2nd CDMA - KPL
iPad 3rd Wifi - J8R, J8T
iPad 3rd CDMA - NQR,NQV
iPad 4th Wifi - 182, 183, 185

iPad Mini 1st Wifi - 193, 196, 637
iPad Mini 2nd Wifi - CM9
iPad Mini 3rd Wifi - 5V3

iPad Air 1st Wifi - K10, K11, K14
iPad Air 1st Cellular - 4YD
iPad Air 2nd Wifi - 5VJ
iPad Air 2nd Cellular - 5YN

iPhone 4S - TC1
iPhone 6 - 5MG, 5MN
```

(Added the devices from above answer)

Answer (score 2):

iOS-based devices:

- iPad (3rd Generation) (Wi-Fi + 3G CDMA) - NQV
- iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi + Cellular) - 5YN
- iPad mini Retina (2nd Generation) (Wi-Fi) - CM9
- iPhone 6 - 5MG
- iPod touch (5th Generation) - 4JR

iPods (pre-iPod touch):

- 5th Generation (Late 2006) - V9K, V9P, V9M, V9R, V9L, V9N, V9Q, V9S, WU9, WUA, WUB, WUC, X3N (complete list per Apple)
- 5th Generation U2 Special Edition (Late 2006) - W9G (complete list per Apple)
- Classic (120GB) - Y5N, YMU, YMV, YMX (complete list per Apple)
- Nano (3rd generation) - YOP, YOR, YXR, YXT, YXV, YXX (complete list per Apple)
- Shuffle (2nd Generation) (Early 2008) - 1ZH, 1ZK, 1ZM, 1ZP, 1ZR (complete list per Apple)

For names, we use:

- iPad - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471
- iPhone - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201296
- iPod - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1353
- Apple TV - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200008

Comment: @tubedogg Nice edit - should we sort the bullets alphabetically (easier for various editors to keep it clean and non-duplicated) - your findings on the multiple endings makes having the names first make much more sense